# regular expression to match repeated characters?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm looking for a `perl` regular expression that will match strings made of only the same letters.

It should match `aa`, `aaa`, `aaaa`, `aaaaa` and so on, but not `aabb`, `abba`, `aaab`, `aaaabaa` and so on.

I know that I can use `\1` to refer back to the first character like `/(.)\1/`, but that would also match `aabb`. Any advice?

Comment: Take a look to anchors of begin and end of line. They will help.

Comment: `.` matches any character, and I'm pretty sure it matches whitespace if you use the /s flag (for treating input as a single line). You can match only letters if you want, for lower case use `[a-z]` or `[[:lower:]]` and for either case it's `[[:alpha:]]` or `[a-zA-Z]` and upper `[A-Z]` or `[[:upper:]]`

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work for me:

```
/^(.)\1*$/
```

The `^` character matches the beginning of the string, and the `$` matches the end.

The whole expression can be translated into: "At the beginning of the string, match any character, followed by any number of that same character, followed by the end of the string.